# share button in custom listview doesn't work

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm following share a text with button in custom listview but it doesn't work .
this is code for `OnClick` in `ListViewAdapter.java` :

```
OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    String ab = (String) holder.tvComment.getText();
                    holder.tvComment.setText(ab);

                    Toast.makeText(context, ab, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ab);
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");


                    context.startActivity(sendIntent);

                }
                catch (Exception e){
                Log.w("Share Data", "Error!");
                }

            }
        };


        holder.sharebtn.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? Are you sure that onClick method is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);
try {
     context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share"));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't support startactivity !?

Comment: Now check my updated ans you have to give your activity context reference to adapter for start activity.

Comment: tnx for your answer but this is crash and force close... see the log [link] http://xum.ir/images/2014/09/13/error2.jpg

Comment: Are you using this Context context = v.getContext(); context ?

Comment: So that way error came.you have required your activity context not a any View.

Comment: thanks Haresh Chhelana but I don't know how can I set getView() , 'R.layout.row' is my View , please help me

Comment: so ask another question for this and if my ans is useful to you for this question you can approve and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks bro . please answer this : [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823279/how-to-set-view-for-listadapter

Answer (score 0):

try starting your Activity this way

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

> Calling Intent.createChooser() ,passing it your Intent object, it
>   returns a version of your intent that will always display the chooser.
>   This has some advantages:
>
> Even if the user has previously selected a default action for this
>   intent, the chooser will still be displayed. If no applications match,
>   Android displays a system message. You can specify a title for the
>   chooser dialog.